# IEnumerable.Cast() vs casting in IEnumerable.Select()

Tags: c#, linq, casting, enumerable

Suppose I have an `IEnumerable<int>` and I want these to be converted into their ASCII-equivalent characters.

For a single integer, it would just be `(char)i`, so there's always `collection.Select(i => (char)i)`, but I thought it would be a tad cleaner to use `collection.Cast()`.

Can anyone explain why I get an `InvalidCastException` when I use `collection.Cast<char>()` but not with `collection.Select(i => (char)i)`?

Edit: Interestingly enough, when I call `collection.OfType<char>()` I get an empty set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Cast<T>` and `OfType<T>` methods only perform reference and unboxing conversions.  So they can't convert one value type to another value type.

The methods operate on the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, so they're essentially converting from `IEnumerable<object>` to `IEnumerable<T>`.  So, the reason you can't use `Cast<T>` to convert from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<char>` is that same reason that you can't cast a boxed `int` to a `char`.

Essentially, `Cast<char>` in your example fails because the following fails:

```
object ascii = 65;
char ch = (char)ascii;   <- InvalidCastException
```

See Jon Skeet's excellent [EduLinq post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Kinda counter-intuitive, but it makes sense

Comment: The link to Jon Skeet's blog appears to be broken. Here's an alternate: http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/33-CastAndOfType.html

Comment: @TylerGill, this link is broken too

Comment: That article keeps moving. Here's an(other) alternate location:
http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2011/01/13/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-33-cast-and-oftype/